# Where can I buy some good doors?

Tags: sound-fx, feature, library, library-sound-effects

Hey Guys,

I've just landed my first job editing sound effects for a feature film - Yay!

I've also been made in charge of editing doors - The film is a romantic comedy , so nothing fancy - no slams or jail doors, or cave doors.
Just wholesome INT and EXT doors for Apartments, freestanding homes, and the odd shop or two.

Where can I get them/buy them.? (I have Zero time to record them myself)

Kurt

Answer (score 2):

Sound Dogs might be your best bet: http://sounddogs.com/

If you want a lot of door sounds, you could check out Sound Ideas door library: http://sound-ideas.com/9000.html

Answer (score 0):

really? No time to record? Thats seems insane for a feature film. The best time to record doors is often after hours - evenings, weekends, late at night....

Frankly if I was supervising the film you are working on I would be way less impressed with you cutting in the same old library doors that we hear all too often, and way more impressed with you finding/making time to bug your friends and locate some appropriate locations and doors and record them....

Is it really time thats the issue?

Comment: In all fairness, I've been on some MOWs and full features which require a full BG and FX turnaround in only 2-3 weeks tops.  It's a luxury if we get 4-5 weeks - it's a common experience at least in LA, while some top tier shows likely have months.  So if the asker only has what I'm guessing could be 2-3 weeks, 4 tops, I'd say that it would be fair to say that there is not enough time to record doors.

Comment: @Tim - I understand what you mean with recording doors, but i'd really invest the bit of extra time I have in creating a sound for the lead character's little electric vehicle, which appears all throughout the film


Comment: @Stavrosound so in a 2-3 week period, if each door recording session takes one hour (15min travel there, 30min recording, 15 min back) then  I still don't see why recording 2-5 doors a week should be so impossible....

Comment: I guess my angle is about priorities... which Kurt has clarified & fair enough!